# Update Multiple cell in coloumn 2 in every rows in datagredvew vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hi every one i need to help please . 
i have datagridview i want to update cell in coloumn 2 in every rows when i am click update button ..

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dgvTestsRes.Rows.Count
    d.EditData(String.Format("Update sampleResult set samTestResult='{0}' where samResID={1}", dgvTestsRes.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString(), dgvTestsRes(8, dgvTestsRes.SelectedRows(0).Index).Value.ToString()))
Next
```

[image]

Comment: If index starts from `0` then range must be from `0 to Rows.Count-1` otherwise it will through an out of range error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Try

    For Each Line As DataGridViewRow In dgvTestRes.Rows

         Line.Cells(1).Value = <YourValue>   <- The column starts from 0, so, 1 = column 2

    Next

Catch

End Try
```